# Elasticsearch - How to get the sum of fields with terms?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to get a sum of some fields, with terms (let's say, number of files of specific user with Id).

First I tried:

```
_mainManager.Client.Search<object>
            (q => q
            .Type("Mail")
            .Filter(c => c.Term("SentMail_Sender_Id", userId))
            .Aggregations(a => a.Terms("sum", g => g.Field("SentMail_Upload_Files_Count")))
            .Size(1));
```

But no luck in Agg property, so I tried this:

```
_mainManager.Client.Search<object>
            (q => q
            .Type("Mail")
            .Aggregations(a => a.Filter("fil", b => b.Filter(c => c.Term("SentMail_Sender_Id", userId))).Sum("sum", f => f.Field("SentMail_Upload_Files_Count"))));
```

But then again, no luck there.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code gives you the result that you need I thing:

```
PUT /mail/message/1
{
  "SentMail_Sender_Id":1,
  "SentMail_Upload_Files_Count":10
}

PUT /mail/message/2
{
  "SentMail_Sender_Id":1,
  "SentMail_Upload_Files_Count":2
}

PUT /mail/message/3
{
  "SentMail_Sender_Id":2,
  "SentMail_Upload_Files_Count":7
}

GET /mail/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "SentMail_Sender_Id": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "total": {
      "stats": {
        "field": "SentMail_Upload_Files_Count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response is:

```
"aggregations": {
      "total": {
         "count": 2,
         "min": 2,
         "max": 10,
         "avg": 6,
         "sum": 12
      }
   }
```